# Can't translate mini cart magento 2

Tags: magento2, translate

I put this under i18n under my theme:
 "View and Edit Cart","Afficher et modifier le panier",module,Magento_Checkout 
also i can't get the translation 
"You added %1 to your shopping cart.","Vous avez ajouté %1 à votre panier.",module,Magento_Wishlist 
and i deleted pub/static and flush cache please help

Comment: try this - https://sanjuantala.wordpress.com/magento2-translating-knockout-template-text/

Comment: ok i will try this and tell you thanks for your replay*

Comment: I can't find the file js-translation.json under my theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have find solution 
open below file and add below translation text

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/i18n/fr_FR.csv

```
"View and edit cart","Afficher et modifier le panier"
"You added %1 to your shopping cart.","Vous avez ajouté %1 à votre panier."
```

after run below command :

```
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
```

**re-run static-content:deploy**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f fr_FR
```

Comment: ok i will try this

Comment: perfect  thanks a lot i need your help please in this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259540/show-a-custom-attribute-instead-of-full-name-if-customer-logged-in-m2?noredirect=1#comment365631_259540

Comment: i already accepted your answer here really very helpful

Comment: my pleasure Welcome!!

Comment: Still working on magento 2.4.3 ( September, 2021 ). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/i18n/fr_FR.csv

```
"View and Edit Cart","Afficher et modifier le panier",module,Magento_Checkout

"You added %1 to your shopping cart.","Vous avez ajouté %1 à votre panier.",module,Magento_Wishlist
```

Then, remove the pub/static content, var/view_preprocessed, then deploy the static content. you can execute the command below

```
rm -rf /pub/static/* && rm -rf /var/view_preprocessed/* && php bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

It should work, you can also translate them via the [inline translate](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1222)

Good luck.